# Displaying a WordPress post in my Magento home page

Tags: php, wordpress, magento

I want to display latest blog post of my wordpress blog to my magento store but having problem in requiring the header file.

I am trying this:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/blog/wp-blog-header.php');


 $args = array('numberposts'     => 5,
    'orderby'=> 'post_date',
    'post_type'       => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'  => ,
    'post_parent'     => ,
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true ); 

  $postslist = get_posts($args);

  foreach($postslist as $post) : set_postdata($post); ?>

 <div><p><?php the_date(); ?></p>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
 </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I would develop a module with a new block that shows the last wordpress blogposts. Therefore you coul use the RSS feed of wordpress or the wordpress json api.

Answer (score 0):

Fishpig makes a great Magento extension to help integrate your Wordpress blog into your Magento site. It's pretty well coded and used on a ton of sites. Plus, it's free. There is functionality there to help you get the latest blog post: http://fishpig.co.uk/wordpress-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

@mukund002 You can to it with a couple of solutions. First you could use the `Fishpig` module, that one does work or you can make it yourself. To do this you have to make some files in your Wordpress blog and also in Magento. There is a manual at http://www.magentowebshop.org/magento-webshop/magento-webshop-wordpress-integration-2/. It is in Dutch, so you can use Google translate. I think this one was made before `fishpig` came with their module.

Answer (score 0):

Fishpig not working in our case but we got the solution somehow. We retrieved the data from wordpress, saved it to database and then called it via **Magento**.